# What to use when sealing floor-to-wall and window-to-wall?

Tags: insulation

During my infiltration (air leakage) test we found two other major places where air is leaking through into my home:

- the joints between the wood floors and the wall (wood) molding
  [image]
- the joints between the windows and the walls
  [image]

In both cases I was told to simply "caulk" it closed, is there something SPECIFIC I should be using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What do I use to fill in the crack between the wall and floor of my tiled bathrooms?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/60863/what-do-i-use-to-fill-in-the-crack-between-the-wall-and-floor-of-my-tiled-bathro)

Comment: @Ecnerwal Not a duplicate - that is WALL and FLOOR in bathroom, this is in rooms with wood flooring and how to deal with windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can caulk the window to the drywall or moulding. I like siliconized latex caulk, but pure silicone can work well too (lasts longer, but not paintable, and collects dust more if it's on a horizontal joint).

For the baseboards, there are a couple of things you can do. If removing them is an option, you can stick foam backer rod between the customary gap between the drywall and the floor, if it's accessible. If that's not an option, you can make sure the baseboard is well-caulked to the wall at the top and the floor at the bottom. Clear caulk works well for this.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the pictures,now things are clear.When it comes to wall-floor joint you can use acrylic based silicone (it is white and in tubes) looks almost identical as wall paint,and it's elastic so it wouldn't crack again.Window-wall joints are a bit more difficult.From what I can see this is a dry wall?IF that is the case im guessing that who ever did this didn't use the flange on the joints,and thats why cracks appear.IF air leak is massive you can also apply some specialised plaster based materials like knauf's fugenfuller.Then just apply walla paint primer,and wall paint and you should be alright.But keep in mind that this just a patch.Real question is where does the air comes from,what I meant where is the crack on the outside and what is causing it.